# This app is incompatible with your device on Google Play and compatible in two versions of the application

Tags: android

I have two applications: the free and paid versions, which differ slightly. One free I see in the market as compatible with my smartphone Honor 9 and the other paid as incompatible.
Please tell me what could be wrong and how to solve it? Answers from similar topics did not help me.
Manifestos permissions and features attached:

***Free compatible:***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

***Paid incompatible:***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Both applications have 
Compile SDK Version: API 27 Android 8.1 Oreo

Min SDK Version: API 15

Target SDK Version: API 27

Comment: There only seem to be two differences. VIBRATE and CHECK_LICENSE. I'm betting on the latter. Remove one or the other to confirm this. If it is CHECK_LICENSE, then you've got an LVL implementation issue and google should be willing to discuss with you what's going on. See "Where to Get Support" here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing

Comment: have you installed latest PlayGames version on your phone?

Comment: The latest updates of all the firmwares, apps and services installed. I also suspect that this is due to a license check. I will explore in this direction. Thank.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved!
There were unnecessary module dependencies in app.
I deleted them and left only the necessary ones.

Comment: Unless you're more specific about what you did I don't think this answer is much helpful to others. Saying which modules caused it is a good start. If you're feeling  adventurous you can put the modules back in and inspect the merged manifest for any entries that may have caused it. You can find that by comparing your new and old apks as well.

Comment: This was a third-party https usage module I wanted to use earlier. In the manifest, I did not change anything, I just deleted it from the dependencies in android studio-menu-project settings-dependencies

Comment: Yes, you didn't change anything in manifest, but libraries contribute their own entries to the resulting manifest. Figure out what the library added to the manifest that made it incompatible. Go to Menu-Tools-Analyze APK and open your new and old apks, then compare their manifests.

Comment: The library was Retrofit. I did not find any differences in the manifests by your method.